# how to display average attendance using a class in python

Tags: python, class, variables, average

I have the following code which has attempted to display the average attendance of all 'created' students. I have a studentCount that counts and prints all students in existence, but cannot seem to arrive at the logic that would do this for attendance. My attempt is below:

**Code**

```
class Student: 
    studentCount=0
    attendanceAverage=0

    def __init__(self, name, form,special_interest,attendance, merits):  #additional variables added here such as special_interest, merits, attendance
        self.name=name
        self.form=form
        self.special_interest=special_interest #additions for the above made here
        self.attendance=attendance
        self.merits=merits

        Student.studentCount+=1
        Student.attendanceAverage=attendance/Student.studentCount

    def displayCount(self):
        print("Total Students:",Student.studentCount)

    def displayStudent(self): 
        print("=Name:",self.name,"=Form:",self.form,"Special Interest:",self.special_interest,"Attendance:",self.attendance,"Merits:",self.merits) #updating the print method for displayStudent to include additional variables

    def displayAttendance(self):
        print("=Name:",self.name,"=Attendance:",self.attendance)



student1=Student("Student1","9F","Guitar",10,200) 
student2=Student("Student2","9R","Chess",7,488) 
student3=Student("Student3","9T","Dance",9,770)
student1.displayStudent() 
student2.displayStudent()
student3.displayStudent()
student3.displayAttendance()

print("Average Attendance:",Student.attendanceAverage)
print("Total Students:",Student.studentCount)  #prints a total count of students
```

**Current Output**

```
=Name: Student1 =Form: 9F Special Interest: Guitar Attendance: 10 Merits: 200
=Name: Student2 =Form: 9R Special Interest: Chess Attendance: 7 Merits: 488
=Name: Student3 =Form: 9T Special Interest: Dance Attendance: 9 Merits: 770
=Name: Student3 =Attendance: 9
Average Attendance: 3.0
Total Students: 3
```

**What is not working ..**

The Average Attendance should obviously be an average of 10, 7 and 9 in this case. I have tried various things like below (trying to declare the sum of attendances first...after which I could calculate the average)...

```
    Student.attendanceCount=? #sum all the existing values for attendance
    Average=attendanceCount/Student.studentCount
```

This was an attempt to first sum the attendances of the various students, and then I would go on to average them. I cannot arrive at the syntax to do the first thing though (obtain all the values for each student). Is there a pythonic or best way to do so?

**For an accepted answer**, could someone please provide a suggested solution to the problem, with suitable comments and explanation as well as, if appropriate, any more elegant ways to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning static variable `Student.attendance` every time you instantiate the `Student` class. So the average attendence is `9 / 3 = 3` according to your code.

You could introduce a sum variable like this:

```
`class Student:
studentCount=0
attendanceAverage=0
attendanceSum = 0

def __init__(self, name, form,special_interest,attendance, merits):  #additional variables added here such as special_interest, merits, attendance
    self.name=name
    self.form=form
    self.special_interest=special_interest #additions for the above made here
    self.attendance=attendance
    self.merits=merits

    Student.studentCount+=1
    Student.attendanceSum += attendance # increment Student's static sum of attendances by this student's attendance
    Student.attendanceAverage = Student.attendanceSum / Student.studentCount`
```

Comment: Your answer is nearly identical to David Jenkins above, but for a different variable, and also produces the same error: Average Attendance: 0.0    ....?

Comment: @MissComputing The output is like this:

Comment: @MissComputing Average Attendance: 8.666666666666666

Comment: @MissComputing I have edited the answer the contain the whole constructor. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Could you please comment your code to clearly explain exactly what this line does: Student.attendanceSum += attendance (assuming it increments or adds to the variable attendanceSum, the attendance value of any created Student?) ....That was the logic I tried to use, but couldn't figure out the syntax - it seems wrong

Comment: Exactly. It adds to the variable `attendanceSum` which was defined statically. That means that its value is not bound to any concrete Student instance but to the class itself. In the constructor we take the parameter `attendance` and add it to the global cumulative variable `attendanceSum`. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are not tracking TOTAL attendance. Every time a Student class object is created you are using a new attendance value, not the accumulated attendance value. The problem line is:

```
Student.attendanceAverage=attendance/Student.studentCount
```

Untested, but should work: Add a new class level variable that tracks total attendance:

```
class Student: 
    studentCount=0
    attendanceAverage=0
    totalAttendance = 0

def __init__(self, name, form,special_interest,attendance, merits):  
    self.name=name
    self.form=form
    self.special_interest=special_interest 
    self.attendance=attendance
    self.merits=merits
    Student.totalAttendance += attendance

    Student.studentCount+=1
    Student.attendanceAverage=Student.totalAttendance/Student.studentCount
```

Comment: Your solution produces the output: Average Attendance: 0.0. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have pointed out why your code isn't working, but is there a specific reason you need a class for this? If you are doing data manipulation using a library like Pandas might be more useful.

```
import pandas as pd

students = pd.DataFrame([['Student1','9F','Guitar',10,200],
                         ['Student2','9R','Chess ',7,488],
                         ['Student3','9T','Dance ',9,770]], 
                        columns=["name", 
                                 "form", 
                                 "special_interest", 
                                 "attendance", 
                                 "merits"])

print("All students")
print(students)
print("")
print("Student3 Attendance: ", students[students['name'] == "Student3"]['attendance'].values[0])
print("Average attendance", students['attendance'].mean())
print("Total Students", len(students))
```

Output:

```
All students
       name form special_interest  attendance  merits
0  Student1   9F           Guitar          10     200
1  Student2   9R           Chess            7     488
2  Student3   9T           Dance            9     770

Student3 Attendance:  9
Average attendance 8.666666666666666
Total Students 3
```

Comment: Classes for teaching/learning purposes - thanks for this - but the solution/answer must utilise the existing structure and my code (classes)

Comment: No problem - the other answers should help in that case.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for working with classes! I know this can be hard to understand in the beginning.

Your problem is that you assign variables within a class, assuming they would be changed globally (i.e. everywhere in your code). If you put `studentCount` within your class `Student`, then it will be changed everytime you address it. The last student has 9 attendances, so `StudentCount` is set to 9 (you are adding 9 to the initial value of 0).

My solution would be to keep track of your objects/students in a list and address their individual attendances OUTSIDE of the class, or put them in a separate class.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, form,special_interest,attendance, merits):  
        self.name=name
        self.form=form
        self.special_interest=special_interest
        self.attendance=attendance
        self.merits=merits

students = [] # create an empty list that will contain all your students as objects of your class
student1=Student("Student1","9F","Guitar",10,200)
students.append(student1) # add your instances/objects to the list
student2=Student("Student2","9R","Chess",7,488)
students.append(student2)
student3=Student("Student3","9T","Dance",9,770)
students.append(student3)

avg = float(sum(student.attendance for student in students))/len(students) # sum up the attendance of all students and divide it by their number
```

Edit: I convert `sum(student.attendance for student in students)` to float, because I work with python 2.7. If I kept the integer value, it would perform an integer division. If you code in python 3.x, you can spare the dtype-conversion.

Comment: Just analysing your answer .....are you able to comment on the first two answers which seem to SUGGEST that the solution (inside a class) is that simple (of course it comes up with an error). Are you saying that it is not possible in the way I've described and as answers 1 and 2 seem to indicate

Comment: As an answer, I refer to what @David Jenkins wrote: "It is not working because you are not tracking TOTAL attendance. Every time a Student class object is created you are using a new attendance value, not the accumulated attendance value". I wouldn't say it's not possible, but it would feel like using a foot to scratch your ear. It would include passing the variable back and forth which makes no sense.

Comment: This is useful - thanks. Isn't passing variables back and forth precisely what happens when you are using classes though? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't say so. Imagine classes as "construction plans" for houses. Creating an instance means taking the plan and physically building the house. You can check for variables and make them individually nice to live in. Now you want your house to have green doors. You make a copy of the plan and specify the color of the doors = green. You wouldn't write into the original plan that you are going to have green doors though. For one, you don't know how others like the color. Second, you don't have the power to change the plan. Whenever someone creates a new copy, the color is changed back.